# ¿conexión TCP/IP sockets - PHP?

Tags: php, socket, server, cliente

Tengo un dispositivo que Permite la comunicación Ethernet TCP/IP 10Base-T/100Base-TX y admite dos conexiones simultáneas.

Quiero crear un script PHP que se conecte al dispositivo para obtener los datos que este devuelve. y obtener este dato desde un cliente web.

Esta es la documentación, formato de transmisión del dispositivo, cómo puede leer estos datos correctamente desde PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este script me conecta con el dispositivo y me imprimí el dato.

```
$fp = fsockopen("172.31.0.159", 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

pero como puedo adaptar este script para leer los datos desde un cliente web.

Estoy un poco perdido, de como puedo manejar una mejor comunicación con PHP.

Pero básicamente lo quiero lograr es un servidor que se conecte al dispositivo. y un cliente que solicite los datos al servidor.

Intente crear un servidor socket basándome en un ejemplo que encontré, con este script, pero cuando ejecuto el archivo PHP, obtengo el siguiente mensaje:  "line 19
socket_bind() falló: razón: 172.31.0.159 Cannot assign requested address"

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Permitir al script esperar para conexiones. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Activar el volcado de salida implícito, así veremos lo que estamo obteniendo
 * mientras llega. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '172.31.0.159';
$port = 23;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() falló: razón: $address " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Enviar instrucciones. */
    $msg = "\nBienvenido al Servidor De Prueba de PHP. \n" .
        "Para salir, escriba 'quit'. Para cerrar el servidor escriba 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() falló: razón: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: Usted dijo '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Comment: Cómo estás ejecutando el script PHP?

Comment: lo estoy ejecutando desde la linea de comando desde Ubuntu server.

Comment: perfecto tu script php practicamente lee los datos y los publica en un web socket. ahora lo que te hace falta es consumirlos, como indicas que quieres mostrar esos datos en tu web (un cliente web.) puedes utilizar javascript, pero para que funciones tienes que mantener tu socket abierto.

Comment: te recomiendo esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHy2zpmsWf8